# MailMessage rejected 4.3.1 by server but is under the exchange limit

Tags: c#, .net, smtpclient, mailmessage

I've looked at a few answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619287/exceeded-storage-allocation-the-server-response-was-4-3-1-message-size-exceeds), but please notice that this is different.

- I have a implementation of MailMessege and SmtpServer in a C#.NET
  class where I'm trying to send attachments on error of a lab
  instrument.
- Here's the thing:   I checked with IT and they said our    exchange
  server is set to have a message max size limit of 50,000    KB.
- However, if I send a message with an attachment over about
  14,500KB, the message gets a

> Exceeded storage allocation. The server response was: 4.3.1
>   Messagesize exceeds fixed maximum message size

Most of the time, we'll be under 10MB, so it's not a big deal, but it just doesn't make sense.  IT suggested I that pursue a developer-side solution since they think it should be going through.

Comment: 14500KB is the size of your document but it needs to be MIME encoded to fit inside an email message which is horribly inefficient and will increase the size dramatically. Try sending the file manually (e.g. with Outlook) and see what happens. Honestly though, if you're sending files that large, then you should be looking at alternative methods, for example, put them on a web server and send a link instead.

Comment: An intermediary smtp server could also have it own limit on attachement size...

Comment: @Jimbot: I'm reached out to the other side of our IT department.  your comment made me realize that the server I'm sending through (an internal server) may have a different limit than the corporate server IT thought I was asking about.  If that turns out to be the cause, you should submit an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any intermediary `SMTP` server could also have it own limit on attachment size. You could check in the message header which server have relay the email.

Comment: It turns out the server I was sending through was different from the o365 server that IT had told me 50MB about, both internal to our corp.  the sending server had a 20MB cap, and the 137% MIME-bloat made the effect cap around 14 MB.  I've now switched to send via the o365 server, leaving me about 30MB (+ bloat) for attachments.

Answer (score 1):

14500KB is the size of your document but it needs to be MIME encoded to fit inside an email message which is horribly inefficient and will increase the size dramatically. Try sending the file manually (e.g. with Outlook) and see what happens. If you take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#MIME) there's a formula for calculating the rough sizes that you actually need.

It may also be the case that any number of intermediate servers is the one with the size restriction. You will have to check the path your message is taking. Look at the headers of the non-delivery receipt and you should be able to determine which server is actually blocking.

Honestly though, if you're sending files that large, then you should be looking at alternative methods, for example, put them on a web server and send a link instead.

Comment: it can't really bloat the file >3x its original size though, can it!?  And yes, there are better solutions, but we've got to get done what we can in a limited time and there isn't an appropriate web server that exists today.  Besides, the number of cases where it's this large are rare, so I don't need an efficient solution.

Comment: that formula you linked to says to expect the attachment to be 137% of the file, or 19.8MB.  this would make sense for a 20MB limit (there's some add'l content in the msg beyond just an attachment), but IT tells me the limit is 50MB...something's still not adding up

Comment: So there is another server that is actually blocking, check the chain to see where it's stuck. Also, does your question have too many zeroes in it? :)

Answer (score -1):

Check that some email addresses only support lowercase letters. If the email address is wrong, it will return